# How to access a specific element of fact in a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, fact

The structure of the facts is

```
  %structure
 student(ID,FirstName,LastName,[courseList]).
 course(CourseCode,CourseTtile,Credits,Level).
```

Following is the fact.

```
 student(20135639,'Mohammed','Abdul Wahab',
 [course('ITIS411','DATABASE SYSTEM IMPLEMENTATION',3,hard),
 course('ITIS412','INFORMATION SECURITY',3 ,easy),
 course('ITIS499','SENIOR PROJECT',3,hard),
 course('ITIS469','AI',3,hard)] ).
```

I want to write a rule that sums the credits hours from the list

```
sum([],0).
sum(H|T,S):-
sum(T,S1),
 S is H + S1.


sumCr(Id, Cr):-
    student(Id,_,_,Courselist),
    sum(Courselist,Cr).
```

The above rule sums  all the elements of the facts in the list but I want to sum  only the Cr value of all facts in the list. So when i run the following query, the output should be.

```
 ?. sumCr(20135639, Cr).
    Cr=12.
```

Comment: `sum` doesn't sum anything; it yields `0` for an empty list and an unbound variable for any longer list.

Comment: I have corrected the mistake @ScottHunter

Comment: `sum(H|T,S)` has syntax issues. Also, your `sum/2` is intended to sum a list of integers, but you're passing it a list of course names (or something, it's not clear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to extract the part of each `course` you want to sum:

```
sum( [], 0 ).
sum( [course(_,_,N,_)|T], Sum ) :-
    sum( T, NT ),
    Sum is NT + N.
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you.